# Azure web app - endpoints depending on domains

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I want to host an Angular App in the Azure Cloud.
This app should be accessible via different domains. But for each domain the app should use a different Endpoint.

mycompany1.com -> restserver.company1/rest
mycompany2.com -> restserver.company2/rest

Is this feasible with only one azure static web app, web app or similar?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by putting a load balancer in front of your Azure Web App. Azure load balancing services can be categorized along two dimensions: global versus regional, and HTTP(S) versus non-HTTP(S).
[REF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/technology-choices/load-balancing-overview)

### Regional

A great regional option is **Azure Application Gateway**. Multiple site hosting enables you to configure more than one web application on the same port of application gateways using public-facing listeners. It allows you to configure a more efficient topology for your deployments by adding up to 100+ websites to one application gateway.

### Global

If you are looking to host your sites across multiple regions then consider using **Azure Front Door**.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/multiple-site-overview

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/configure-web-app?tabs=customdomain%2Cazure-portal

Comment: I would also (or even instead) recommend Azure Front Door. No management overhead like thinking about scaling AppGW

Comment: AFD is a great option if you need multiple region support.  I will update my answer to include AFD.